# ping: sendmsg: No buffer space available

Tags: wifi, ping, buffer

I am running a ping from one of the terminals:

`ping www.google.com`

This runs without any issues indefinitely.
Now on another terminal, I run:

`for i in {1..5}; do speedtest; done`

Now after sometime on the ping terminal, I hit this error:
`ping: sendmsg: No buffer space available`

How do I debug this?